# Vue, Vuetify 2 - How to add buttons to data table footer

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

The title pretty much says it all - I'd like to add a couple of fab buttons to the table footer (with which I plan to CRUD records in the table). Ideally I'd like to move the `Rows per page` and pagination to the left, and add my buttons in on the right, but at this point I'm willing to settle for adding my buttons on the left.

I looked at the [documentation on data table slots](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables), and I thought that `body.append` or `footer` might do it, but couldn't figure out how to translate them into my project, as they don't provide any mark up in the API section (only javascript objects) and none of the examples below the API section has what I'm looking for either.

Here's the code I'm currently using, in case it helps:

```
<v-data-table
  v-model="selected"
  item-key="id"
  class="elevation-1"
  :headers="headers"
  :items="items"
  :search="search"
  :sort-by="['expiry.millis', 'label']"
  :sort-desc="[false, true]"
  multi-sort
  show-select
>

  <template v-slot:top>
    <v-toolbar flat color="white">
      <v-toolbar-title>Inventory</v-toolbar-title>
      <div class="flex-grow-1"></div>
      <v-text-field v-model="search" append-icon="mdi-magnify" label="Search" hide-details class="half-width"></v-text-field>
      <div class="flex-grow-1"></div>

      <v-btn color="error" small fab dark v-if="selected.length > 0"><v-icon>mdi-delete-outline</v-icon></v-btn>
      <v-btn color="deep-purple accent-4" small fab dark class="ml-1"><v-icon>mdi-plus</v-icon></v-btn>
    </v-toolbar>
  </template>

  <template v-slot:item.expiry="{ item }">
    {{ item.expiry.until }}
    <v-icon :title="item.expiry.date.format('DD/MM/YYYY')">mdi-information-outline</v-icon>
  </template>

</v-data-table>
```

As you can see I currently have my buttons in the toolbar, along with the table name and a search bar.

I'm using Vuetify: 2.0.0. Let me know if I need to include any other information and I'll gladly update my question.

Comment: I don't know if this will help you or if it's the supposed way to do it but when I want to add a fab bellow my v-data-table I put the table inside a v-card... Something like: <v-card><v-card-text><v-data-table /></v-card-text><v-btn fab></v-card>

Comment: @MarcelusTrojahn Thanks for the tip, it does kinda work. If you want to change your comment into an answer, I'll accept it if nothing better comes along within the next day or so.

Comment: You can use slots like append or foot. See https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-data-table/#slots-foot

Answer (score 0):

There is markup for `body.append` here:
https://codepen.io/pen/?&editable=true&editors=101 
taken from the page you linked to, the point is it should look like this:
`<template v-slot:body.append>...`

Comment: As Michael mentioned there is also this alternative. I did a few tests and both my alternative or Michael's visually yelled the same result (also, v-slot:footer works too). I had no success in making 2 or more fab buttons look good though... All above alternatives were ok with a single button.

Answer (score 0):

I faked the buttons with adding v-card under the data table. check my pen

https://codepen.io/rveruna/pen/jONewxj

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-content>
      <v-container>
        <template>
          <v-data-table
            :headers="headers"
            :items="desserts"
            :items-per-page="5"
            class="elevation-1"
          ></v-data-table>
        </template>
        <v-card style="border-top-left-radius: 0; border-top-right-radius: 0; box-shadow: 0px 5px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0px 5px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);">
          <v-card-text>
            <div style="position: absolute; top: -42px" class="body-1 font-weight-bold">
              <v-icon class="mdi-18px roundedIcon success" style="color: white">mdi-check</v-icon> Selected domains:
            </div>
            <template>
              <v-chip class="mr-2 mb-2" close>blb</v-chip>
            </template>
            <template>
              <v-chip class="mb-2" close>and bla more</v-chip>
              </template>
          </v-card-text>
          <v-card-actions class="actionsDetails" style="background: rgb(249, 249, 249); border-top-left-radius: 0; border-top-right-radius: 0">

          <v-spacer></v-spacer>
          <v-btn text normal >Export All</v-btn>

          </v-card-actions>

        </v-card>
      </v-container>
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the suggestion of @MarcelusTrojahn, I've used a `<v-data-table />` inside a `<v-card>`. The table would be enclosed in the `<v-card-text>` and the buttons container at the end

For instance :

```javascript
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-content>
      <v-card>
        <v-card-text class="table-container">
          <v-data-table
            :headers="headers"
            :items="desserts"
            :items-per-page="5"
            class="elevation-1"
          ></v-data-table>
        </v-card-text>
        <div class="buttons-container">
          <v-btn color="primary" class="footerBtn">
            <v-icon right dark style='margin-right: 5px;'>mdi-chevron-left</v-icon>Prev
          </v-btn>
          <span class="footerBtn pageCount">{{ `${currentPageFrom} - ${currentPageTo}` }}</span>
          <v-btn color="primary" class="footerBtn">Next<v-icon right dark>mdi-chevron-right</v-icon></v-btn>
        </div>
      </v-card> 
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

See the codepen attached : https://codepen.io/bertrandmartel/pen/mdJYaBO